# Displaying raster attributes on data driven pages

Tags: arcmap, raster, fields-attributes, dynamic, data-driven-pages

I have a feature class of 50 properties that are ranked. I have a photo for each property stored in a raster attribute column (in the feature class) called "Picture". I am trying to create a Dynamic text attribute for the picture column to use with my Data Driven Pages. I have struck out so far on getting the images to appear in the layout. Any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to change the paths of picture elements in map documents with Data Driven Pages (there may be a way with Production Mapping, but I don't have access to that extension so I couldn't tell you). However, it is possible to do this in Python using the Mapping module of ArcPy. You would add a placeholder picture in your map document template, add an Element Name in the "Size and Position" tab of the picture element, then edit the `sourceImage` property of that [`PictureElement`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000s000000) for each map you are creating. Overall, I've found `arcpy.mapping` to be much more flexible and powerful than data driven pages, and definitely worth learning.